# Calculate position of projector

Tags: math, projection

I am projecting a rectangle on a table with a beamer and I want to calculate the absolute position of the beamer in the space from the destortion of this rectangle. I know the absolute position (in 3D) of all the corners of the rectangle that is projected on the table.

I dont know how to get started with this and cannot find much usefull info on the internet. 
Can someone provide some tips please?

Comment: is the beamer always "level" such that the projection would be a trapezoid?  The math would be a lot easier if the movement is only in two axes and not three.

Comment: no the beamer is not always projecting perpendicular on the table surface so the  projection can be a trapezoid indeed

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you know.  I'll choose the easiest:

If you know the position of the original rectangle, just find the intersection of the lines that go through the matching corners.